# How to perform update for each users in table at different time stamp in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

For a CRM System In Codeigniter I Have A Admin module which add the balance to reselle. Now reseller has an option to view his own users and he can add to remove balance. Now if have a radio button on editing that balance is either Yes or No.Here i know the logic but don't know how to implement the below: One the reseller edits a user and sets the balance to yes i want to count 30 days, after 30 days the balance would be reset to no. So i think i should fetch all the users and check when thier balance was set to yes. if its already 30 days then i have a update cron job file which will reset the balance to No. Now i dont know how to do this? how could i check each user? i am very confused about the code and logic. Below is my code to edit the User.

```
public function edit ($id = NULL)
{

     $usertype=$this->session->userdata('usertype');
    if($usertype ==="reseller")
    {

    // Fetch a user or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new();
    }

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('sip_id','sip_pass','name','email', 'password','phone','status','created','balance'));
        $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);
        $this->user_m->save($data, $id);
        redirect('reseller/user');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'reseller/user/edit';
    $this->load->view('reseller/_layout_main', $this->data);


}
else{
    $this->load->view('permission');
}

}
```

the Reseller:
[image: reseller]

The User Table:

[image: User Table]

Comment: Logic : You can store start date and end date in database, your cron will check end date is today if yes the update it to NO. this cron will run once in day.

Comment: So you mean that when reseller edit user balance to yes i should store a filed called start date and at the same time get a end data and store it in database?

Comment: I would create a trigger in your database, which is looking for «balance === yes», calculating the reset date and time and save it to a field. Your cron is looking vor this field and resets the balance.

Comment: @Joerg Your logic seems charm to me can you help me with code please?

Comment: What do you need? The trigger thing or the cron? Could you please add some of your database fields to your post? It will be easier for you and me to discuss.

Comment: Okay ! i want help with trigger ! how to mark the starting date and ending date? Trigger will be fired when there would be update from Balance==no to yes

Comment: @Joerg I have added the Desc of my tables in question. Pleas check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger example for your database (MySQL):

```
CREATE TRIGGER resetBalance
    BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table_name
    IF new.balance = "yes" THEN 
    SET NEW.reset = ADDDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
    End IF
```

**UPDATE:**

Let's say, you have a field in your db called balance, where you store the value yes or no. (I would prefer here a boolean type.)

And let's say, that you have a field called reset, where you save the resetdate for the balance. The reset field should be a datetime.

If you make an update to any balance field and the «new» entry of the balance field is yes, the database will insert in the reset field the current date + 30 days.

New means the new entry which you save in the db, there is also an old value. That is the value, which was before updating in the column.

That's all.

In your cron, you just check the reset field, do some logic or what ever and delete the value in the reset field.

**UPDATE 2:**

I just saw, that you have a created and modified field in your db. Here is also the best way to use triggers.

Before Insert:

```
set new.created = NOW();
```

Before Update:

```
set new.modified = NOW();
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Today is trigger-day ;-))

Let's say you have a tblUsers and a tblResellers. In the tblResellers you would like to set a reset date, based on a balance field in tblUsers. Then you should create a Trigger in tblResellers like this:

```
BEGIN
set @userBalance = (SELECT balance FROM tblUsers WHERE id = old.userid);

IF @userBalance = "yes" THEN 
    SET NEW.reset = ADDDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
    ELSE
    SET NEW.reset = "";
    END IF;
END
```

In the second row, I define a variable «userBalance» which gets its value from tblUsers. In the where clause I use a field from tblResellers (userid), which is corresponding with an ID in tblUsers.

The rows above are easy: Checking the value of userBalance, make some decisions and set the reset date.

I think this trigger will match not all your needs, but you get a feeling of how to do it. If you change the code, make it step by step, to debug triggers is a little bit tricky.

Comment: what is new.balance can you please explain me? do i need to add any other fileds please check the updated question i have added my table description

Comment: Hey Thanks! One more help Is it safe to use trigger where i am having shared hosting? or i should have dedicated server?

Comment: It is save, the trigger is bundled with your database user.

Comment: Thanks A Lot for your help.

Comment: Hi the trigger will be started whenever there is update on any field! how to fire the trigger only for that user whose balance has been set to yes! i mean some user maybe have another date when he would have been allotted balance

Comment: can you please explain what this means : WHERE id = old.userid

Comment: also i pasted this code in phpmyadmin create new trigger but it showed me error updating new rows is not allowed in trigger

Comment: do i have to add any other fields in my tables for 3rd update ?? i know m getting too much dependent but i have no idea about trigger and its syntax!